# How to apply order on custom taxonomy and custom meta key on custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, customization, query-posts

Here is the code in am using

```
$arg= array(
    'post_type' => 'vr_listing',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'vr_listing_status',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'Active', 'Pending','Sold')
        )
    ),
    'meta_key' => 'vr_list_price',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);

query_posts($arg);
```

Each listing has a particular status assigned to it i.e Active,pending,status(different terms in custom taxonomy) 
What i want to achieve is to first order  by price using meta key and at the same time i want to get the results from custom taxonomy from different terms but one by one.
e.g first i want to achieve all the results from Active term and then pending and then sold

Any ideas how  can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way would be to run the loop for each status and only output posts that match the current status:

```
$statuses = array( 'Active', 'Pending', 'Sold' );
foreach( $statuses as $status ):
    echo $status;
    while( have_posts() ):
        the_post();
        if( has_term( $status, 'vr_listing_status' ) ):
            the_title();
        endif;
    endwhile;
    rewind_posts();
endforeach;
```

A couple of additional notes - if this is the main query, alter it via the [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action rather than using `query_posts` in the template. If this is an additional query and not the main query, use [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).